# Express the following power series as a raional function

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, rational-functions

Consider the following power series:

$f(x) = \sum\limits_{i>=1} 2^{i-1}x^{3i}$ = $\ x^3 + 2x^6 + 4x^9 + ...$
$g(x) = \sum\limits_{i=2}^{20} f(x)^{i}$

Express both f(x) and g(x) as rational functions, ie p(x)/q(x) where P(x) and q(x) are polynomials.

How would I go about doing this? Is there some kind of algorithm or pattern I can follow?

Comment: The series defining $f(x)$ is geometric.  Do you know how to deal with those?

Comment: I can see that now when I change it into the form below. The formula for that is 1/(1-r) which does make sense to me. The limits on the summation are more difficult though. I can't find anywhere how that affects the geometric series formula.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$2^{i-1}x^{3i}=\frac12\left(2x^3\right)^i$$

So assuming

$$2|x|^3<1\;\;\text{(why?)}\;,\;\;\text{we get}\;\;\sum_{k=1}^\infty2^{i-1}x^{3i}=\frac12\frac{2x^3}{1-2x^3}$$

Comment: why is there a 2x^3 in the numerator? Is it because it starts at k=1 instead of k=0?

Comment: Yes: the first element in an infinite geometric series must appear in the denominator.